Where is specified the Attribute class of UML?
In UML 2.4.1 (infrastructure), page 32/230, I see that title (in the model) is instance of Attribute (in the metamodel).

Source: https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Infrastructure/PDF
However, I don't see any Attribute class in this specification.
Where is specified the Attribute class of UML?
Is it an error?
Can you provide a fix for it?
Thank you.
Best regards.

The class is Property. A property associated with a class in the collection OwnedAttributes is an Attribute.

@GeertBellekens yes indeed, the Property class is supposed to be used. The Attribute class doesn't exist. So, for me it is an error in the specification which is weird because I see that it is present since UML 2.0 and not fixed in UML 2.4.1. Why do you think they used the Attribute class that is not part of UML?

Probably legacy left over from UML 1.x?
